# Why do I get a copied line numbers warning using DECODE in Oracle SQL server?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, decode

I am receiving a copied line warning when I am using decode in Oracle SQL Server. I can't seem to find any information on this type of warning anywhere. Why am I receiving this warning?

Image of the warning

[image: Image of the Warning]

This is my query

```
SELECT 
DECODE(value, 
1, 'OA', 
2, 'EZ', 
3, 'THD',
4, 'EDIWBI',
5, 'EManual',
6, 'BS',
7, 'OETY'
) ORDER_SOURCE
from my_table;
```

When I move line four up to line three (shown below), the warning disappears but then I get a suggestion to expand my SQL statement. I structured my DECODE statement like that to make it easier to read.

```
SELECT 
DECODE(value, 
1, 'OA', 2, 'EZ', 
3, 'THD',
4, 'EDIWBI',
5, 'EManual',
6, 'BS',
7, 'OETY'
) ORDER_SOURCE
from my_table;
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SQL Server database? Run `select @@version;` or `select * from V$VERSION;` to find out.

Comment: Show the exact error you are getting.

Comment: What's a "Copied Line Warning"?

Comment: @Gary_W Warning reads 'Copied line numbers'. I'm not getting any errors, so I don't have an Oracle Error Code to share, but I edited my post to share an image of the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is simple: **ignore the warning**. It is pointless. I believe software (SQL Developer) misidentified a "problem" (as there's none).

You can, though, navigate (with the mouse) to "Fix it", click it and you'll see what happens - all numbers (except 1) will be removed and *then* you'll get invalid query, as opposed to a valid one you have now.

---

Though, perhaps you'd want to consider using a `CASE` expression instead of `DECODE` for easier/simpler readability and maintenance; in simple cases (as yours) it doesn't really matter, but - for complex problems, `DECODE` is a nightmare.